# Google Firebase Realtime Database Encryption

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I see in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy) that Firebase Realtime Database is encrypted.
But there are some terms I don't fully understand:

1. Firebase services encrypt data in transit using HTTPS and logically isolate customer data. What does `logically isolate customer data.` mean?
2. "In addition, several Firebase services also encrypt their data at rest: Firebase Realtime Database Firebase Test Lab" Can somebody explain this in layman's terms?

Answer (score 1):

1. Firebase stores user's data on the same physical server, but the data is isolated by a computer program (computer logic). It's not physically isolated from one another.
2. When your data is not "in use" it's encrypted. So when you data is being worked on by a service it has to be not encrypted.